# search for parameters with square brackets in an access query

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbconnection

I try to identify in C# ,a DB Access with thousands of queries, only the queries with fictitious parameters,

(eg. Select id, Nation, Name from someTable where Nation = **[Give a Nation]**).

I tried with **GetOleDbSchemaTable** but with no luck.
I also tried to use **MSysQueries** and **MSysObjects** from Access and then retrieve the info in C # but with no luck.

How can you help me?

Comment: You might have difficulties with looking for square brackets, as these are also used to "escape" special characters in table/field names, such as spaces - for example, if a field is called `Nation Name`, then it would be listed in the SQL of the query as `[Nation Name]`.

Comment: Use a third-party add-in for searching. I used Rick Fisher's Find and Replace but I understand it is no longer available and had a cost. Consider V-Tools which is a freebie. Do the search within Access to locate those queries.

Comment: What does 'no luck' mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens?

Comment: in GetOleDbSchemaTable the view is not returned while others without dummy parameters are returned. with the MSysQueries I don't find anything that returns me that the query is with dummy parameters

Comment: the tool is not useful to me, I need programmatically to extract the MSAccess queries with parameters, to extract the parameters, ask the parameter value on screen and execute the query. finally return the result in Excel sheet. All in c #

Comment: Then you need to write code that gets the SQL string of query objects, searches for a WHERE keyword and if found then searches WHERE clause substring for `= [`. Join MSysQueries with MSysObjects to get the query object name. First build a query that joins tables and has filter criteria for the WHERE keyword. Go to Access and examine those two tables. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to ref the interop - this one:

```
using System.Data.OleDb
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao

public void ShowParms()
{
var strPath = @"C:\Users\AlbertKallal\source\repos\DesktopFun\test44.accdb";

Database db;
DBEngine dbACE = new DBEngine();
db = dbACE.OpenDatabase(strPath);
QueryDef query;
Parameter qParm;

foreach (var query in db.QueryDefs)
{
    if (Strings.Left(query.Name, 1) != "~")
    {
        Debug.Print("Query name = " + query.Name);
        // parmaters
        foreach (var qParm in query.Parameters)
            Debug.Print("query parmater name = " + qParm.Name + "  type = " + qParm.Type);
    }
}
}
```

the above will list out each query - and if it has parameters - then it will list out those.